# css: 20px gutter between 50% width divs

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have a container div at 100% width, with 2 `.block` divs inside it, both at 50% width, display inline-block and floated left. Is it at all possible to have a consistent 20px gutter in between these divs?
I have tried the unsophisticated method of setting their widths to 49% each and having a 2% right margin on the left one, but ideally I'd like a consistent 20px gutter inbetween these 2 divs, if possible.
jsFiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/D6U3t/ 
HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0;
    width: 100%; height: 300px;
    background-color: silver;
}

.block {
    position: relative;
    width: 50%; height: 200px;
    background-color: red;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: [Will this suit](http://jsfiddle.net/D6U3t/2/)?

Comment: **Note:** This is not the best solution. But if you are in a hurry, you can have a look at [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/D6U3t/3/) as an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can help you if a wrapper div is acceptable.
The secret is (as it often is) in `* {box-sizing: border-box;}`.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fWu65/).

Comment: Using this techniqe you can get an arbitrary number of columns.

Comment: +1, although I wouldn't suggest putting `border-box` on the `*` selector unless you really need to; just apply it to the specific element.

Comment: Depends on how you roll I guess. I kinda just took Paul Irish's word for it, and I haven't looked back since. http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/

Answer (score 0):

you have to add one more class. i think its work.

```
    .block:last-child {
     margin-left:20px;
     float:right;
     }
```

& Reduce the .block width to 49%.

Check out the fiddile : http://jsfiddle.net/D6U3t/14/

Thanks

Comment: That looks horrible on large screens!

Comment: It doesn't matter.  As long as you're decreasing the width by a percentage point and using fixed-pixel width for margin, you're not going to get the desired result.  Now it looks wrong on a small screen.

Answer (score 0):

I would work with a padding on the parent container and then have the child container to be 100% width and 100% height.

Check out my JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/D6U3t/10/

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="block first">
        <div class="inner-block"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="block second">
        <div class="inner-block"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%;
    background-color: silver;
}

.block {
    position: relative;
    width: 50%; 
    height: 200px;
    float: left;
}

.block.first {
    padding: 0 10px 0 0;
}

.block.second {
    padding: 0 0 0 10px;
}

.inner-block {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used an inner container to solve the problem.

`fiddle:` http://jsfiddle.net/kpwp7/4/

Answer (score 0):

If your [browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc) requirements allow for it, you can use the [calc()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) CSS function:

http://codepen.io/troywarr/pen/MaVKGe?editors=110

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; 
    left: 0;
    width: 100%; 
    height: 300px;
    background-color: silver;
}

.block {
    width: calc(50% - 10px); /* subtract half of 20px gutter */
    height: 200px;
    background-color: red;
}

.block:first-child {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px; /* half of 20px gutter */
}

.block:last-child {
  float: right;
  margin-left: 10px; /* half of 20px gutter */
}
```